# Java ScheduledExecuter only runs 1 of 2 Runnables, if they are scheduled at the exactly same time

Tags: java, task, scheduled-tasks, scheduler

I want to execute two Tasks with Java ScheduledExecuter. The tasks may not run asynchron, so I only allow 1 thread.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler= Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
```

The schedulers work is mainly to always execute the same task every few seconds. This works perfectly fine. 
But there is a problem: The user is able to generate tasks at runtime and schedule them at a specific time he can choose. this works in 99,9% of cases, but if the user decides to execute 2 or more tasks at the exact same time, the scheduler only executes one of them and simply doesnt execute the others. The other tasks never get executed.
Example:

**This works:**

```
Calendar toRun = Calendar.getInstance(); //for example 17:00
toRun.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
toRun.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
toRun.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long delay = toRun.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
Task_TaskOne t1 = new Task_TaskOne();
scheduler.schedule(t1, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

Calendar toRun2 = Calendar.getInstance(); //for example 17:01
toRun2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
toRun2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 1);
toRun2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long delay2 = toRun2.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
Task_TaskTwo t2 = new Task_TaskTwo();
scheduler.schedule(t2, delay2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

**In this case only the first task gets executed, the 2nd one never does:**

```
Calendar toRun = Calendar.getInstance(); //for example 17:00
toRun.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
toRun.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
toRun.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long delay = toRun.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
Task_TaskOne t1 = new Task_TaskOne();
scheduler.schedule(t1, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));

Calendar toRun2 = Calendar.getInstance(); //for example 17:00
toRun2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
toRun2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
toRun2.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
long delay2 = toRun2.getTimeInMillis() - System.currentTimeMillis();
Task_TaskTwo t2 = new Task_TaskTwo();
scheduler.schedule(t2, delay2, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
```

In my opinion this is weird. Shouldnt the scheduler have a que (like TimerTask has) and execute the 2nd task just after the first one? 
Also does anyone has an easy fix for it? Multiple threads are not an option.

Comment: It doesn't matter how many tasks you add to executor and doesn't matter if they are scheduled for the same moment of time. All tasks are added to the queue and will be executed. How do you know that the 2nd task was not started? Have you any logging in the task that confirms that?

Comment: Did the first task end properly?

Comment: yes, the first task ends properly. Also i can ensure the 2nd task doesnt even start, because in my application all tasks are logged extensivly. Furthermore i have a internal arraylist where i store all tasks and the first thing each task does on run() is to remove itself from this arraylist. However, the 2nd task stays in, completly untouched by the scheduler.
In addition to that everything works if there is a slight delay, the bug only accurs if they are scheduled at the same time. Thats why i exclude the problem is inside the task logic.